# 403 Forbidden on files with different names but identical content and permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, http-status-code-403, forbidden

I'm running CentOS 6.3 and Apache 2.2.15.

I'm using the defaults setup for apache.  The files I'm serving are in

```
/var/www/html
```

Here are two of them

```
[root@gisele html]# ls -l *-production-1.0.6.pdf 
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 171769 Jan  1 21:12 copy-installation-production-1.0.6.pdf
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 171769 Jan  1 20:59 installation-production-1.0.6.pdf
```

The copy file is a file created by doing

```
cp installation-production-1.0.6.pdf copy-installation-production-1.0.6.pdf
```

Through a virtual host mapping I'm accessing these documents.

`copy-installation-production-1.0.6.pdf` will serve.
`installation-production-1.0.6.pdf` returns a 403 forbidden.

The only difference, is that the original file was copied onto the server from another machine.

Any idea why this original file will not serve but the copy will?

Answer (score 3):

Well, disabling SELinux it's just a temporary workaround, not a solution. [We don't wan't to make Dan Walsh cry](http://stopdisablingselinux.com) ;)

Try one of these options:

```
chcon --reference=/var/www/html/FileThatCanBeServed /var/www/html/FileWithError403
```

or

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html /var/www/html/
```

or

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/
```

Always check the SELinux context of the files that are accessible with `ls -lZ`, then use `chcon` with the `--reference` option to copy the context to other files.

Comment: I'm glad he's crying! :)  Some of the code of SELinux contributed by the NSA.

Comment: Haha.. yeah you've got a good point there! :)

Answer (score 2):

Gah, SELinux.  Same probalem as this question:  [Apache serves some files, others get 403](https://serverfault.com/questions/309233/apache-serves-some-files-others-get-403?rq=1)

Turn off SELinux being the solution.

http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

There should be a prompt in the CentOS installation

```
Is this machine primarily a 
Server (1) / Desktop (2)
1/2...? 1

Would you like to run into bizarre errors later on?
Y/N...? y

Installing SELinux.
```